# How do I break down if statement inside the while loop to two separate funcitons?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

The idea is to keep repeat the input unless enter 'm'. I'm trying to pass the latinize_sentence function to input_latin after 'else:'(to be exact)

However, The latinize_sentence function would better not be changed if not necessary, so it may be tested separately later.

Write a program that repeatedly asks the user to enter sentences and prints
out the Bee Latin versions of those sentences.
The user can enter 'm' to quit the program.

```py
def main():
    """Set up the main function to process the latin format"""
    sentence = input_latin("Enter English sentence: ")
    print_latin(sentence)


def input_latin(words):
    """Make the input repeat over unless encounter 'm'"""
    looping = False
    while not looping:
        sentence = input(words)
        if sentence == 'm':
            looping = True
            return sentence
        else:
            latin = latinize_sentence(sentence)
            return latin


def latinize_sentence(sentence):
    """return the Bee Latin version of the sentence."""
    latin = sentence.lower().split()
    for word_num in range(len(latin)):
        if latin[word_num][0] in "aeiou" or sentence[word_num][0].isalpha() == False:
            latin[word_num] += 'buzz'
        else:
            latin[word_num] = latin[word_num][1:] + \
                latin[word_num][0]
            latin[word_num] += 'uzz'
    latin = ' '.join(latin)
    return latin
    

def print_latin(sentence):
    """Print out the result"""
    if sentence == 'm':
        print("oodbyeguzz")
    else:
        print("Bee latin = {}".format(sentence))
  
    
main()
```

## Example test:

## Testing main()

```
Bee latin = rytuzz histuzz outbuzz
Enter English sentence: and that #Repeatly
Bee latin = andbuzz hattuzz
Enter English sentence: m #stop repeating until type 'm'
oodbyeguzz
Enter English sentence: this is a longer sentence
Bee latin = histuzz isbuzz abuzz ongerluzz entencesuzz
Enter English sentence: wow and this is even longer than the last
Bee latin = owwuzz andbuzz histuzz isbuzz evenbuzz ongerluzz hantuzz hetuzz astluzz

#Testing latinize_sentence:

english = latinize_sentence("try this out")
print(english)
rytuzz histuzz outbuzz
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making things complicated unnecessarily:
U can achieve this simply by:

```py
def latinize_sentence(sentence):
    """return the Bee Latin version of the sentence."""
    latin = sentence.lower().split(" ")
    for word_num in range(len(latin)):
        if (latin[word_num][0] in "aeiou") or (latin[word_num][0].isalpha() == False):
            latin[word_num] += 'buzz'
        else:
            latin[word_num] = latin[word_num][1:] + latin[word_num][0]
            latin[word_num] += 'uzz'
    latin = ' '.join(latin)
    return latin


def print_latin(sentence):
    """Print out the result"""
    print("Bee latin = {}".format(sentence))

def main():
    while(True):
        user_input = input("Enter English sentence: ")
        if(user_input == "m"):
            print("oodbyeguzz")
            break
        else:
            print_latin(latinize_sentence(user_input))

main()
```